# No individual test results displayed on TFS 2015 with Maven and JUnit

Tags: maven, junit, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

so I set up a none-XAML-build on TFS 2015 to build and test my Maven project. Which works as expected. Then I added a build step to consolidate test results via **/TEST-*.xml and publish them as a test run to tfs, which also works, but...

on the `testrun summary` page it shows the correct number of passed tests and it also attached the JUnit XML-files, though on the `test results` page it does not show anything :( Those .xml-files are JUnit `<testsuite>` results with multiple `<testcase>` entries and I expected for TFS to display the result for each individual test including it's duration, but it does only show a blank page.

Anybody has the same problem or even a solution (except publishing by tfs api :p) Cheers!

Comment: Could you see the detail test result in the build logs? Any Valuable information about it?

Comment: When I open "Tests" in build result the total tests and summary is fine but below it says this build doesn't contain any results: http://imgur.com/6Ax2Zac

In the test results both test suites are attached:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter -->
<testsuite hostname="WS-321" name="com.example.Test" tests="2" failures="0" timestamp="1 Apr 2016 12:02:16 GMT" time="0.000" errors="0">
  <testcase name="Test2" time="0.000" classname="com.example.Test"/>
  <testcase name="Test1" time="0.000" classname="com.example.Test"/>
</testsuite>

Comment: Are you using "Publish Test Results" task to publish the results? If yes, do you select "JUnit" as the test result format? Refer to this link for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/11/24/testing-java-applications-with-visual-studio-team-services/

Comment: Yes, I use Publish Test Results and it's set to JUnit. I now disabled TestNG, but it is the same result. No individual tests are listed under "Test results".

Comment: Does the result show if you change "Outcome" to "Passed"?

Comment: They are briefly displayed and then disappear. Upon checking html the container thats holds the HTML for the result is on `display:none` but I cannot figure out, since `Outcome` is set correctly and no filter is set. I will check tomorrow at another computer, but I already checked Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

There are no additional settings to show the test result info. It will automatically show the every detail information about each test. 
[image]

Since the test run summary show the right info. The test must run successfully. Please check your build log whether there are some valuable info. And also double check your build template configuration. Here is a blog telling you how to use vnext build with Marven and run the tests for your reference: 
[Building Java code on Linux using VSO Build.vNext](http://realalm.com/2015/07/01/building-java-code-on-linux-using-vso-build-vnext/)

Comment: I played around and I saw now that the results are displayed for a very brief second and then it displays "Sequence contains no elements", but just before that the results were there, so weird. I tried using Internet Explorer, to no avail. So there is obviously a problem with the website and not the parsing of the junit results :/ 

The website of the build shows `results-section outer-section` with `display:none` even though my filter says `Group By Container` and `Outcome All`. But the test run itself shows 0 results, very fishy.

Guess I need to continue googleing.